# Scala: JavaFx Tableview does not display data

Tags: scala, javafx, tableview

So I have tried to load in some data into my Tableview but it doesnt work because every time I start my application the tableview is empty but it doesn't show the prompt message that its actually empty.

My Code:

```
     @FXML var anchorpane: AnchorPane = _

  // Example for the Product Entity
  @FXML var tableview: TableView[Product] = _
  @FXML var c1: TableColumn[Product,Integer] = _
  @FXML var c2: TableColumn[Product,String] = _
  @FXML var c3: TableColumn[Product,Double] = _



  //create data for inserting in an observerList
  val data: ObservableList[Product] = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Product(55,"hallo",33.0)
    new Product(10,"hello",20.3)
  )



  override def initialize(location: URL, resources: ResourceBundle): Unit = {
    //Für die columns namen setzen
    c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,Integer]("id"))
    c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,String]("name"))
    c3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,Double]("price"))

    //inserting data from the observableArrayList
    tableview.setItems(data)
  }
```

But my tableview remains empty...
Here is how it looks like:
[image: My App with the tableview]

My Product class:

```
    package fhj.swengb.homework.dbtool

import java.sql.{ResultSet, Connection, Statement}

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

/**
  * Created by loete on 27.11.2015.
  */

object Product extends Db.DbEntity[Product] {

  val dropTableSql = "drop table if exists product"
  val createTableSql = "create table product (id integer, name string, price double)"
  val insertSql = "insert into product (id, name, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"


  def reTable(stmt: Statement): Int = {
    stmt.executeUpdate(Product.dropTableSql)
    stmt.executeUpdate(Product.createTableSql)
  }

  def toDb(c: Connection)(p: Product): Int = {
    val pstmt = c.prepareStatement(insertSql)
    pstmt.setInt(1, p.id)
    pstmt.setString(2, p.name)
    pstmt.setDouble(3, p.price)
    pstmt.executeUpdate()
  }

  def fromDb(rs: ResultSet): List[Product] = {
    val lb: ListBuffer[Product] = new ListBuffer[Product]()
    while (rs.next()) lb.append(Product(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getDouble("price")))
    lb.toList
  }

  def queryAll(con: Connection): ResultSet = query(con)("select * from product")

}

case class Product(id:Int, name: String, price:Double) extends Db.DbEntity[Product] {

  def reTable(stmt: Statement): Int = 0

  def toDb(c: Connection)(t: Product): Int = 0

  def fromDb(rs: ResultSet): List[Product] = List()

  def dropTableSql: String = "drop table if exists product"

  def createTableSql: String = "create table product (id integer, name String, price Double"

  def insertSql: String = "insert into person (id, name, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Product` class?

Comment: @James_D added my Product class.

Comment: I don't know Scala, so maybe these are created "automatically", but (in Java) the `PropertyValueFactory` is expecting to find either a `idProperty()` method or a `getId()` method (etc for other columns): see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html). So you probably either need to implement these, or (probably better) define your own `Callback` implementations to provide to [`setCellValueFactory(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-)

Comment: hmm I know what you mean but my Product class was wirtten a little bit diferrent like it's used to be....

Comment: Then implement the `Callback` for the cell value factory yourself, instead of using the predefined `PropertyValueFactory`.